# how to change date formate this coming data api 2023-01-02 formate 02-01-2023

Tags: android, api, date, calendar

**2023-01-02 are coming from this text api. Not sure how to change them to 02-01-2023**```

```
TextView txt_Date_Number;

txt_Date_Number.setText(post.Date_Number);

txt_Date_Number = findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
```

How to change date formate android

Comment: Use java.time: `LocalDate.parse("2023-01-02").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu"))` gives `02-01-2023`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Java:**

```
   String dateFromAPI = "2023-01-02";
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateFromAPI);
            String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dateFromAPI);  
            Log.e("test1", finalDate);
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
```

**For Kotlin:**

```
        val dateFromAPI = "2023-01-02";
        val date: Date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateFromAPI)
        val finalDate=DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", date)  //output 02-01-2023
```

Comment: TextView txt_Date_Number;

txt_Date_Number.setText(post.Date_Number);

txt_Date_Number = findViewById(R.id.tv_date); how to set this text

Comment: I think you are making a mistake while assigning id with textview variable. Your sequence is not correct. It should be like.

TextView txt_Date_Number;

txt_Date_Number = findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

txt_Date_Number.setText(post.Date_Number);

Comment: To set text in your TextView you need to add this code.

 ```String dateFromAPI = post.Date_Number  //"2023-01-02";
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateFromAPI);
            String finalDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dateFromAPI);  
            Log.e("test1", finalDate);
TextView txt_Date_Number;        
txt_Date_Number = findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
txt_Date_Number.setText(finalDate);
} catch (Exception exception) {

        }
```

Comment: bro this text coming api  txt_Date_Number.setText(post.Date_Number) api text how to convert date formate exmple 2023-01-02 convert  02-01-2023

Comment: I have already mentioned in above comment and in answer how can you convert date format.

Comment: @ode Chef
ok sorry

Comment: If my answer is useful for you so please up_vote it

Comment: why crash application 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.Tamiltv.newspaper.models.Recipe.Date_Number' on a null

Comment: In your models class Date_Number is null. First set its value

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).